# Url for the asp:Image gets messed up

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, url

I am dynamically adding usercontrols to my page:

- when the user clicks on the button, jquery ajax method executes, which calls my web method
- the web method returns my usercontrol rendered as string
- in the success part of ajax call the received html is appended to a placeholder

Method to render my usercontrol:

```
public static string RenderUserControlAsString(string path)
{
    var page = new PageOverride();
    var viewControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(path);
    page.Controls.Add(viewControl);
    var output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, output, true);
    return output.ToString();
}
```

This works OK, but I have problems with ImageUrl of my asp:Image element (my usercontrol contains multiple elements and asp:Image is just one of them):

```
<asp:Image ID="imgDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'"/>
```

The `ImageUrl` gets transformed to `../images/delete.gif`, which is not OK. Actially, the `ImageUrl` always receives two dots and a slash infront of it. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Edit - project structure:

**Root:**

- images

  - delete.gif
  - ...
- WebControls

  - MyWebControl.ascx
  - ...
- MyWebService.asmx
- MyPage.aspx

Comment: In which folders your user control and page reside ?

Comment: @Coder: added project structure to the question, see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I just added an override method to my web control:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
      base.OnPreRender(e);

      // Don't use ImageUrl, set fixed src attribute.
      imgDelete.Attributes["src"] = "images/delete.gif";
}
```

The drawback is, that the image is displayed only on pages, which reside in root folder, but that works for me.

Another way would be with jquery livequery plugin:

```
$('.Delete').livequery(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/delete.gif');
});
```

Edit - I could probably also set CssClass to the image button and set `background: url(../images/add.gif)` with css...

Answer (score 1):

When user control gets added to the aspx webpage, it looks for the images relative to your webpage path, two dots with a forward slash `../` means go back 1 step, in your case it searches for `../images/delete.gif` which is invalid for `MyPage.aspx` as both your web page and `images` folders are under `root`.

Either place your user control and webpage in same folder or change the path to `images/delete.gif`.

**Edit:** Following hierarchy don't require you to place user control / webpage in same folder or changing path to `images` folder.

Root:

- images

  delete.gif
  ...
- WebControls

  MyWebControl.ascx
      ...
- WebPages

  MyPage.aspx